# Open superset of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be an open set such that $\mathbb{Q}\subset S$. We can also define a set $T=\mathbb{R}\setminus S$. I have been trying to prove or disprove whether $T$ could be uncountable. I suspect $T$ has to be at most countable, is my intuition correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is reasonable, but incorrect. HINT: the rationals are countable, so we can list them as $\mathbb{Q}=\{q_1, q_2, q_3, . . .\}$ (obviously this listing isn't "in order," in any sense, but that's fine).

Now, let $U_n=(q_n-2^{-n}, q_n+2^{-n})$. Each $U_n$ is open, so the union $V=\bigcup U_n$ is open, and clearly $V$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$. Do you see how to show that $\mathbb{R}\setminus V$ is uncountable?

---

If you are unfamiliar with [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure), the above hint will be very difficult. An alternate approach is via the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem): let $C$ be the Cantor set, and show that there is some real $r$ such that $C+r=\{x+r: x\in C\}$ contains no rational numbers. Then the complement of $C+r$ is open, contains the rationals, and has uncountable complement. HINT: To use BCT, show that for each rational $q$, the set $B_q=\{r: q\in C+r\}$ is nowhere dense. Then, since there are only countably many rationals, BCT implies that $\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} B_q$ is meager, and hence $\not=\mathbb{R}$ . . .

Comment: I don't know anything about Lebesgue measures, but it surely seems like a powerful tool for these kind of questions. I've accepted this answer since it's twofold and the first response.

Comment: @Kaj It is indeed super powerful! Here's a lightning-fast primer: the *outer measure* $\mu$ of a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is basically how hard it is to "cover" $A$ with open intervals: $\mu(A)$ is the infimum, over all families $\{U_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of open intervals $U_n=(a_n, b_n)$ with $\bigcup U_n\supseteq A$, of $\sum b_n-a_n$. For example, $\mu(\mathbb{Q})=0$: look at the argument above, replacing "$n$" with "$n+k$" for $k$ a constant, and note that as $k\rightarrow\infty$ the total size of the $U_n$s goes to $0$. (cont'd)

Comment: Showing that a set has outer measure zero is usually not too hard; the complicated part is showing the opposite. For example, "obviously" $\mu([0, 1])$ should be $1$; but it was probably not obvious that $\mu(\mathbb{Q})=0$, so you might well be worried! Here the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) is crucial. First we show that any *finite* cover of $[0, 1]$ by open intervals has "total length" at least $1$; then, via HB, we show that any cover of $[0, 1]$ by open intervals at all has a finite subcover, so we're done. (cont'd)

Comment: Lebesgue measure is just outer measure - *restricted to the **measurable sets**.* It turns out that outer measure has some weird properties, e.g. there are disjoint $A, B$ with $\mu(A\cup B)\not=\mu(A)\cup\mu(B)$. Roughly speaking, the measurable sets are the sets that aren't silly like this; they include the open sets, the closed sets, the Borel sets (like the rationals and the irrationals), etc. For many applications (including this problem) the basic properties of outer measure, though, are sufficient (the key here is: no set of positive outer measure is countable!).

Answer (score 3):

Expressed differently, the condition on $T$ is that it can have no rational elements and no rational limit points.

But even without measure theory, we can easily specify such a $T$ that is uncountable -- for example the set of all numbers in $(0,1)$ in which the $n$th digit of the decimal representation is $3$ when $n$ is a perfect square, and either $4$ or $5$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you are working in the topological space $\mathbb{R}$)

There's a nice trick to this with measure theory. By using the fact that the rationals are countable — and thus enumerable — you can construct $S$ by picking a positive real number $m$ and defining $S$ to be the union of

- An open set of length $m/2$ containing on the first rational
- An open set of length $m/4$ containing on the second rational
- An open set of length $m/8$ containing on the third rational
- An open set of length $m/16$ containing on the fourth rational
- $\vdots$

Then the total measure of $S$ is clearly no greater than the sum of the lengths of these intervals — i.e. $m$. In particular, it is finite.

Therefore, the measure of the corresponding $T$ must be infinite, and thus uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

AS rationals form a countable set, enumerate them, and take an open interval of length $\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$ around the $n$-th rational number. Union of these open intervals is a candidate for $S$ in your question. The measure for this open set is less than $\epsilon$. So the complement has positive measure. Can it be countable?